# Convert POST parameter to mongoose schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have been experimenting on Mongoose and NodeJs lately, and I appreciate some help here. Let's assume I have a Mongoose Schema as below

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var findOrCreate = require('mongoose-findorcreate')

var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    email: String,
    password: {type: String, default: ''},
    name: String,
    createdDate: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
    updatedDate: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
    rawDataFromOauth: {type: Array}
});
userSchema.plugin(findOrCreate);
var user = mongoose.model('user', userSchema);

module.exports = {
    user: user
};
```

I will be sending a POST request which will have a user JSON object as below

```
{
    "email": "blahblah@gmail.com",
    "name": "i am blah blah",
}
```

**Q1**
Is there any way I can convert this JSON to the mongoose schema in one shot? currently I am mapping it one after other using req.body.user.email, req.body.user.name etc which is really painful.

NOTE: Actual scenario has around 20+ variables.

**Q2**
My goal is to use findOrCreate() provided by https://github.com/drudge/mongoose-findorcreate on this Mongoose model. I tried to do the following

```
new userModel.((req.body.user)).findOrCreate({email: req.user.email}, function (err, user){
//do some magic here
});
```

and

```
userModel.hydrate((req.body.user)).findOrCreate({email: req.user.email}, function (err, user){
//do some magic here
});
```

I bump into this error

```
TypeError: (intermediate value).findOrCreate is not a function
```

and

```
TypeError: userModel.hydrate(...).findOrCreate is not a function
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: For your POST value problem, I think you can use `Object.keys()` to grab all the key values from your req.body.user, and loop through them to initialize.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Is that not same as req.body.user.email etc etc? Looping again is an overhead as i need to initialise the variable one by one. Is there no one step solution like a serialiser and deserialiser?

Comment: Did you test bodymen? ;)